# How can I stop the class view add member function wizard from adding (void) to argumentless functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, methods, vs-classview

The post [VS2008 win32 project defaults - remove default precompiled headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593349/vs2008-win32-project-defaults-remove-default-precompiled-headers) outlines how you can edit the wizards to remove the use of precompiled headers.

Can I do something similar to stop the add member classview wizard from adding (void) to argumentless functions?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you not want void in arguments list? Some platforms require the void for clean compile...

Comment: There's no need of this disambiguation in C++. `int foo();` is `int foo(void);` But back to C, `int foo();` is in fact `int foo(...);`