# Pre-Compiled Header (why need to include in every source file)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, precompiled-headers

I am trying to understand pre-compiled headers. So I set up the following sample project:

pch.hpp

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

pch.cpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "pch.hpp"
```

Vector.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

class Vector {
public:
    Vector(const size_t N, const int init);

private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};
```

Vector.cpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "pch.hpp"
#include "Vector.hpp"

Vector::Vector(const size_t N, const int init)
    : m_data(N, init) { }
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "pch.hpp"
#include "Vector.hpp"

int main() {
    const Vector v1(3, 5);
}
```

I did this in VS 2022 by marking `pch.hpp` as the pre-compiled header file under **Project Properties** --> **C++** --> **Pre-Compiled Headers** --> **Header File** with `Use (/Yu)`. And setting `pch.cpp` as `Create (/Yc)`.

Now, when I remove `#include "pch.hpp"` in `Vector.cpp` or `Source.cpp`, I get this error:

```
File         Vector.cpp
Line         10
Severity     Error
Code         C1010
Description  unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header.
             Did you forget to add '#include "pch.hpp"' to your source?
```

However, if I disable pre-compiled headers, everything compiles fine. As one would expect.

So, it seems that with pre-compiled headers enabled, I now need to put `#include "pch.hpp"` into every other source file? Even though `#include "Vector.hpp"` already includes `pch.hpp`? Is it possible to avoid having to put `#include "pch.hpp"` into all my other source files?

I ask, because I have a much larger code base (than the example above), and I thought I could essentially replace all instances of `#include <vector>` with `#include "pch.hpp"` and be done. But having to add `#include "pch.hpp"` to numerous cpp files, requires me to touch a lot of files (and seems counter-intuitive).

Apologies for the possibly naive question, as I am new to pre-compiled headers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precompiled Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293538/precompiled-headers)

Comment: Basically, it's a requirement because you told it, for a given project, that all files must include it. You can turn it off for specific files, but if you want to include the precompiled header, it must appear in the same source file.

Comment: Important part is that precompiled header is not a convenience header to list all the useful header files in one place and then to include a this single header everywhere. It is a compilation time reducing technique.

Comment: if you remove `#include "pch.hpp"` then `#include <vector>` is missing. Please post the code that does cause the error. Posting code that has no error and describing what has to be changed is rather error-prone

Comment: You can enable/disable precompiled headers separately per `.cpp` file: `Right lick on the file in solution explorer -> Properties -> C++ -> Precompiled Headers`